# increment the value of a key in an object that corresponds to a key in Radis

Tags: node.js, redis

i have one object in redis database that key is `hello`

there is one object in hello key for example:

```
{
  a: 'foo',
  b: 'bar',
  c: 0
}
```

I want to increment `c` in `hello` key of redis.

read this link [Redis - String Incr Command](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/strings_incr.htm#:%7E:text=Redis%20%2D%20String%20Incr%20Command,-Advertisements&text=Redis%20INCR%20command%20is%20used,be%20represented%20as%20an%20integer.), but this tutorial tells us how to increase the value of a radius key, not the value of a key in the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `hincrby` see: https://redis.io/commands/hincrby/

This command will let you update a hash field by key.